# Javascript check within acceptable range

Tags: javascript, numbers, range, decimal

I have a range high and a range low and I need to be able to display if the input number is within the acceptable range, or if it is higher or lower than the acceptable range.

Currently, my javascript code looks like this but I keep getting the message saying it is an invalid entry.

it needs to be able to handle decimal places as the high and low are based on user preference.

```
    var highRange = 17.80;
    var lowRange = 6.90;
    var valueToCheck = (rText.value);

    function checkRange() {
        var msg = 'Invalid entry';
        if ((valueToCheck > 0.00) && (valueToCheck <= lowRange)) { msg = 'LOW'; }
        if ((valueToCheck > lowRange) && (valueToCheck <= highRange)) { msg = 'NORMAL'; }
        if ((valueToCheck > highRange)) { msg = 'HIGH'; }
        rangeValue = msg;
    }
```

I just don't understand why it isn't working, lol.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried parseFloat on valueToCheck ? Sure valueToCheck is not negative ?

Comment: Is that a magical function? Just kidding. Where is it being called?

Comment: Use parseFloat() on your var valueToCheck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
    var highRange = 17.80;
    var lowRange = 6.90;
   

    function checkRange() {
       var valueToCheck = document.getElementById('rText').value;
        var msg = 'Invalid entry';
        if ((valueToCheck > 0.00) && (valueToCheck <= lowRange)) { msg = 'LOW'; }
        if ((valueToCheck > lowRange) && (valueToCheck <= highRange)) { msg = 'NORMAL'; }
        if ((valueToCheck > highRange)) { msg = 'HIGH'; }
        document.getElementById('rangeValue').innerHTML = msg;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rText" >
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="checkRange()">
<p id="rangeValue"></p>
```

The problem was you put the `valueToCheck` outside the function.. Therefore when the page is loaded it already gets the null value of the input..

The `valueToCheck` must be inside the function in order to get what are the changes in the input..

Comment: @rafon peenoise gaming ka?

Comment: That was it! Thank you for pointing it out. I've just been looking at it for the last 20 minutes trying to figure out what the hell I did wrong. Cheers :-)

Comment: @cloudseeker I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: @ShadowFiend baket?

Comment: @ShadowFiend gg

Answer (score 0):

Use parseFloat to convert your string to a float.
`var valueToCheck = parseFloat(rText.value);`